# Input with multiline

Tags: html

I am using this code to show a textbox and a button:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form name="form" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="text_box" size="50"/>
            <input type="submit" id="search-submit" value="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I make the input to be with multiline?

Comment: use `<textarea>` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to have a multiline input is to use a textarea:

```
<textarea name='multiline_ip' rows='5' cols='15'></textarea>
```